# Non-power series proof that $|\log (1 + z)| \le -\log (1 - |z|)$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, logarithms

Given $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $|z| < 1$, we have the bound

\begin{align*}
|\log (1 + z)|
  &= \left| \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}z^n}{n} \right| \\
  &\le \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{|z|^n}{n} \\
  &= -\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(-|z|)^n}{n} \\
  &= -\log (1 - |z|)
\end{align*}

That is, the largest magnitude of $\log (1 + z)$ within a given radius $r$ of $z = 0$ is achieved at $z = -r$.

**Question:** Is there a simple derivation of this bound that uses only "algebraic" or other simple properties of $\log z$, and not the power series?

I'm being slightly vague about what properties are allowed, but in particular I want to avoid infinite series.  (The motivation is a proof that's easy to formalize as part of https://github.com/girving/ray; I could do the series proof but it seems like there should be something simpler.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $|z|<1$. With the change of integration variables $t=1+zs$, we find that
$$
\log (1 + z) = \int_1^{1 + z} {\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{t}}  = z\int_0^1 {\frac{{{\rm d}s}}{{1 + zs}}} .
$$
Then
$$
\left| {\log (1 + z)} \right| \le \left| z \right|\int_0^1 {\frac{{{\rm d}s}}{{1 - \left| z \right|s}}}  =  - \log (1 - \left| z \right|).
$$

Comment: Thanks, that does work and is indeed a bit simpler to formalize (easier side conditions), though it's basically the power series proof in integral form.  Interesting if there isn't anything more algebraic, but I'll go ahead and accept.